# Maven: javaee-api vs jboss-javaee-6.0

Tags: java, maven, jboss, dependencies, java-ee-6

I want a Java JEE6 project built with maven, and I want it *standard*

So, I put this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

A project like this, it is supposed to run in every JEE6 container compatible (jboss, geronimo, glashfish, etc.)

Then, why this jboss dependency exists?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

If I use it, am I tied to jboss so I can only use this server with this application?

Is it not preferable to always use the standard javaee-api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard api is crippled, i. e. method bodies are missing. This turns out when testing. I have once run into this pitfall and was not very happy with it.

Therefore it is advisiable to use another package as reference.

You can have a closer look on [Adam Biens Blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee)

You can also make profiles for different deployment environments if you really need. However, essentially I agree, this is sadly not a very pleasant circumstance.

For having issues with testing, you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116220/how-can-i-use-different-jars-for-compiling-and-testing-in-maven).

Edit:
By the way, since now this might be interessting. This issue is gone for the javaee-(web-)api for **Java EE 7** ([source](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/javaee_7_heals_crippled_jars))

Comment: Note the `org.jboss.spec` dependencies are only the API dependencies. They do not in any way tie you the JBoss platforms.

Comment: For future reference - The following error occurs very frequently with this paradox. `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file`

Answer (score 2):

The first solution with java-api dependence is the right way: your application in ideal case should not be cared about server environment under what it works. For unit test you can use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), which helps you to test enterprise beans at "home" without headache. If you are using jboss-javaee, are you sure, that your application will deployed and work fine on another server, than jboss?