# Failed to load ApplicationContext ¿?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, maven, junit

Why am I getting "Failed to load ApplicationContext" with Spring, jUnit with JavaConfig?

Here is my test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
    public class CloseDTOTest {

    @Autowired
    private CloseDTO closeDTO;
    @Autowired
    private TrdDAO trdDAO;
    @Autowired  
    private TrmopDAO trmopDAO;
    @Autowired  
    private PaytDAO paytDAO;
    @Autowired  
    private SrvtypeDAO srvtypeDAO;
    private Trmop trmop;
    private Date date;
    private Trd trd;
    private Payt payt;
    private Srvtype srvtype;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.trmop = this.trmopDAO.findById(113);
        this.date = new DateManager().convert("2015-04-07");
        this.trd = trdDAO.findById(1);
        this.payt = paytDAO.findByUid("EFE");
        this.srvtype = srvtypeDAO.findByUid("POS");
    }


    @Test
    public void testCloseOpPre(){
        System.out.println("---.testClosePre.----");
        CloseOpTO closeOpTO= this.closeDTO.closeOpPre(srvtype, payt, trmop);
        System.out.println(closeOpTO.toString());

    }
}
```

And I get this error

```
GRAVE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@12fad49] to prepare test instance [org.pt.servicespay.core.operations.DTO.CloseDTOTest@119b0f3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.accntRcrdBO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.pt.servicespay.core.operations.DAO.DeptrdsysDAO org.pt.servicespay.core.operations.BO.accntrcrd.AccntRcrdBO.deptrdsysDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deptrdsysDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.pt.servicespay.core.operations.DAO.DeptrdsysDAO org.pt.servicespay.core.operations.BO.accntrcrd.AccntRcrdBO.deptrdsysDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deptrdsysDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deptrdsysDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 67 more
```

As you can see, I have the applicationContext file in: *file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml*.

I really dont know why this is happening? :(

these are my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- ZK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId> <artifactId>zkex</artifactId> 
        <version>3.6.3</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.zkoss.common</groupId> 
        <artifactId>zweb</artifactId> <version>7.0.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.zkoss.common</groupId> <artifactId>zcommon</artifactId> <version>7.0.2</version> 
        </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ZK-BOOTSTRAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>zk-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- POSTGRES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUNIT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.6</version> <type>jar</type> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> <version>1.5.6</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- TwiP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.twip</groupId>
        <artifactId>twip</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WSDL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jarperreport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JavaCSV -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jumpmind.symmetric</groupId>
        <artifactId>symmetric-csv</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- core library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JAXB support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.scannotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON Provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JavaEE -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jDOM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAVA MAIL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- GSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId> <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId> 
        <version>1.9</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId> <version>2.1</version> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Let me guess you have a dependency on the Java EE 6 API? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518148/maven-javaee-api-vs-jboss-javaee-6-0.

Comment: I have it, and I commented it, but I'm still having same problem, if you want take a look below where I did post my pom.xml and tell me if any of those apis is crippled, pls.

Comment: Please don't add it as an answer modify/improve your original question instead.

Comment: ok sorry! im new here

Comment: You have the `javaee-web-api` remove it as mentioned that is borked... As explained here (it is the same as with the javaee api.). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518148/maven-javaee-api-vs-jboss-javaee-6-0%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing javax validation interface library. 
Adding below dependency to your project will resolve the problem.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

comment below dependency.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

add this dependency to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Didn't work :( But I think you're right, maybe its a problem in the dependency, here's my dependencies, which one of them is related to jUnit test? I mean, to change any of the dependencies in case they're corrupted!

Comment: Thanks man, really. That was the problem. But it took me some time to do it cuz I had other libraries crippled (jackson-json and two dependencies duplciated)

Comment: and it was only necesary to comment the javaee-web-api, if i put the other dependencies you said, it wasn't work eather.